# React JS Adding Data to an Array through Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging

https://codesandbox.io/live/1e7d9781bb1

I'm creating an app that has user inputs. Using these inputs, the user will put in a selection. For this example, it's using the MuI component for autocomplete and has 4 options available.

When this selection is made, I would like to append this selection to the 'style' key in the dict. On submit I would like to handle this function async and console.log it right now just to ensure all the data is collected. I will late post this with an API. I have most things created but I think there's an issue with how my data is setup. I'm sure someone smarter then me will be aware of where i'm going wrong!

Have removed quite a bit of content but here is the barebones:

```
export default function JobParams() {

  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [dataTransfer, setdataTransfer] = useState({
    style: {},
    location: {},
    salary: {},
  });
  //trial
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = ['Style ', 'Location ', 'Salary '];
  const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);

  function goNextPage () {
    if (page === 4) return;
    setPage(page => page+1)
  }
  
  function goBackPage () {
    setPage(page=> page-1)
    setCompleted(false)
  }

  function updateData(type, newData) {
    setdataTransfer(dataTransfer => {
      return {...dataTransfer, [type]: newData}
    })
  }
  
  async function submit() {
    //insert post method here or just hold the state 
      setSubmitting(true)
      await sleep(2000);
      // console.log(dataTransfer)
      setSubmitting(false)
      setCompleted(true)
    
  }



    return (

                    {/* Content goes here */}
                    {page === 0 && <ParamSelection data={dataTransfer.style} update={updateData}/>}
                    {page === 1 && <LocationSelection data={dataTransfer.location} update={updateData}/>}
                    {page === 2 && <SalarySelection data={dataTransfer.salary} update={updateData}/>}


                  {page === 0 && <ButtonSelectionEnd>
                    {page !== 0 &&<Button onClick={goBackPage}>Back</Button>}
                    {page !== 2 && <Button onClick={goNextPage}>Next</Button>}
                    {page === 2 && <Button type="submit" startIcon={isSubmitting ? <CircularProgress size="1rem"/> : null} onClick={submit} disabled={isSubmitting} onSubmit={async (values) => 
                      { await sleep(3000); 
                        console.log(values)
                        setCompleted(true)
                      }}
                      >
                        Submit
                      </Button>}
                  </ButtonSelectionEnd>}
                  
                  {page !== 0 && <ButtonSelection>
                    {page !== 0 &&<Button onClick={goBackPage}>Back</Button>}
                    {page !== 2 && <Button onClick={goNextPage}>Next</Button>}
                    {page === 2 && <Button type="submit" startIcon={isSubmitting ? <CircularProgress size="1rem"/> : null} onClick={submit} disabled={isSubmitting} onSubmit={async (values) => 
                      { await sleep(3000); 
                        console.log(values)
                        setCompleted(true)
                      }}
                      >
                        Submit
                      </Button>}
                  </ButtonSelection>}


    );
  }


function ParamSelection({data, update}){
  const newData={};

  return (
    <SelectionContainer>
      <StyleSelect onClick={()=> update('style', newData)}/>
    </SelectionContainer>
  )
}

function LocationSelection({data, update}){
  const newData={};

  return (
    <SelectionContainer>
      <LocationSelect/>
    </SelectionContainer>
  )
}

function SalarySelection({data, update}){
  return (
    <SelectionContainer>
      Show me the money!
    </SelectionContainer>
  )
}
```

The functions at the bottom are separate components, each which are the input fields.

As stated. I would like each one to log to an array, perhaps through:

```
  const [dataTransfer, setdataTransfer] = useState({
    style: {},
    location: {},
    salary: {},
  });
```

If you console log this currently you get an empty array.

What's wrong with my function?

```
 function updateData(type, newData) {
    setdataTransfer(dataTransfer => {
      return {...dataTransfer, [type]: newData}
    })
  }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your function with this:

```
function updateData(type, newData) {
setdataTransfer(dataTransfer, dataTransfer[type] = newData)
}
```

or

```
function updateData(type, newData) {
setdataTransfer({...dataTransfer, [type]: newData})
}
```

Comment: Hi user, this is written in JS not TS. However neither seems to work!

Comment: I got it to work. The problem is the passing of your function to the other components and passing the value of onChange to the updateData function
https://gyazo.com/0d6df75203edcc803875af4627c901f8

Comment: Hi User! Thanks a lot for sending that screenshot. I'm happy to see that you've gotten this to work! For some reason i'm unable to replicate the fix on my side. Do you mind copying your file to a sandbox like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-leftpad-dfshx?file=/src/App.js. I'm a bit of a react noob when it comes to props and passing values. Do you mind if you throw it in there please? I appreciate the help so far

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wright-8fnwe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thankyou so much user14408018! I can see now the error with how the data was being handled. I thankyou so much for this. Honestly thankyou so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function updateData(type, newData) {
    setdataTransfer({...dataTransfer, [type]: newData})
  }
```

Comment: Hi geoff, this does not appear to resolve the issue, can you please clarify if this is to replace the original func?

Comment: I had a typo, corrected it now.

Comment: Hi Geoff, I appreciate the assistance. However it doesn't appear to be working! https://gyazo.com/c5b8109d5c08f93da288dd1190eb6a09. Trying to make this easier for you to help me, honestly thankyou so much. Please take a look at the demo I setup for you! What's the best way to append the data at the end? Please see: https://codesandbox.io/live/1e7d9781bb1